# Как перерисовывать customView при каждой передаче состояния?

Tags: android, customview

Есть `customView` для `pin activity`, при нажатии на цифры он должен окрашиваться в другой цвет, то есть показывать сколько символов пин кода введено, каждый раз при нажатии я передаю в класс `customView` число введенных символов, и каждый раз мне нужно его перерисовывать. Как мне это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс для `customView`

```
public class IndicatorWithCircles extends AppCompatTextView {

    private static final int DEFAULT_COUNT_CIRCLES = 4;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CIRCLE_RADIUS_DP = 14;
    private static final int DEFAULT_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_CIRCLE_DP = DEFAULT_CIRCLE_RADIUS_DP;
    private static final int DEFAULT_STROKE_THICKNESS_DP = 4;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CIRCLE_STROKE_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CIRCLE_INSIDE_COLOR = Color.GRAY;
    private static final int DEFAULT_ACTIVE_FILL_CIRCLE = 0;

    private Paint paintStroke;
    private Paint paintInside;
    private int countCircles;
    private int circleRadius;
    private int distanceBetween;
    private int strokeThickness;
    private int strokeColor = Color.BLACK;
    private int insideColor = Color.GRAY;
    private int activeFillCircles;

    public IndicatorWithCircles(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public IndicatorWithCircles(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public IndicatorWithCircles(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initialize(attrs);
    }

    private void initialize(@Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        initializeAttrs(attrs);
        initializeUI();
}

private void initializeAttrs(@Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (attrs != null){
        final TypedArray array = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.IndicatorWithCircles);
        try {
            countCircles = array.getInteger(R.styleable.IndicatorWithCircles_count_circles,
                    DEFAULT_COUNT_CIRCLES);
            circleRadius = array.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.IndicatorWithCircles_circle_radius,
                    DEFAULT_CIRCLE_RADIUS_DP);
            distanceBetween = array.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.IndicatorWithCircles_distance_between_circles,
                    DEFAULT_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_CIRCLE_DP);
            strokeThickness = array.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.IndicatorWithCircles_stroke_thickness,
                    DEFAULT_STROKE_THICKNESS_DP);
            strokeColor = array.getColor(R.styleable.IndicatorWithCircles_circle_stroke_color,
                    DEFAULT_CIRCLE_STROKE_COLOR);
            insideColor = array.getColor(R.styleable.IndicatorWithCircles_circle_inside_color,
                    DEFAULT_CIRCLE_INSIDE_COLOR);
            activeFillCircles = array.getInteger(R.styleable.IndicatorWithCircles_active_fill_circle,
                    DEFAULT_ACTIVE_FILL_CIRCLE);
        } catch (Throwable throwable){
            Log.d("", throwable.getMessage());
        } finally {
            array.recycle();
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("", "AttributeSet is null");
    }
}

private int dpToPx(int dp){
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return (int) (dp * displayMetrics.density);
}
//Передаю число введенных символов
public void setActiveFillCircles(int activeFillCircles) {
    if (activeFillCircles >= countCircles)
        this.activeFillCircles = countCircles;
    else
        this.activeFillCircles = activeFillCircles;
}

@Contract(pure = true)
private int minInteger(){
    return activeFillCircles <= countCircles ? activeFillCircles : countCircles;
}

private void initializeUI() {
    paintStroke = new Paint();
    paintStroke.setColor(strokeColor);
    paintStroke.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paintStroke.setStrokeWidth(strokeThickness);
    paintStroke.setAntiAlias(true);
    paintInside = new Paint();
    paintInside.setColor(insideColor);
    paintInside.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paintInside.setAntiAlias(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    drawStroke(canvas);
    drawInside(canvas);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int desiredWidth = countCircles * (circleRadius + distanceBetween);
    int desiredHeight = (circleRadius * 3) * 2;

    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int width;
    int height;

    if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        width = widthSize;
    } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        width = Math.min(desiredWidth, widthSize);
    } else {
        width = desiredWidth;
    }

    if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        height = heightSize;
    } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        height = Math.min(desiredHeight, heightSize);
    } else {
        height = desiredHeight;
    }
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
//Рисую сначала внешнюю линию
private void drawStroke(Canvas canvas){
    for (int i = 1; i <= countCircles ; i++) {
        canvas.drawCircle(distanceBetween * i + circleRadius + strokeThickness,
                circleRadius * 3, circleRadius, paintStroke);
    }
}
//Окрашиваю окружность, должна быть равна числу введенных символов
private void drawInside(Canvas canvas){
    for (int i = 1; i <= minInteger(); i++) {
        canvas.drawCircle(distanceBetween * i + circleRadius + strokeThickness,
                circleRadius * 3, circleRadius, paintInside);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается есть готовый метод `invalidate()`, который как раз и обновляет состояние `customview`